# Delete the file object of form after saving or open the file before form saving

Tags: python, django

What I want is like this below

upload the file -> validate -> store in db.

```
form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

form.save() # real file stored in directory

#open file and validate..

df = pd.read_csv(form.document.path)

if validate(df):
 pass:
else:
 form.remove() # error occurs "DocumentForm object has no attribute 'remove'"
```

Then now, I have two ideas.

Is there a way to delete the object in `model` from `Form` object???

or

Is there a way to open the file before it is stored in directory???

My `form` and `model` classes are below

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(label='comment',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'comment'}))
    class Meta:
        model = MyDocument
        fields = {'description','document'}

class MyDocument(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents'
    ,validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv', ])]
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not doing it as you already started, through a file validator since the **validators** argument supports a list of validators which will be executed in the given order. Or if you don't want to include it on the model, you can create a form and define a file field with a list of validators same way as defined in models.

```
def validate_doc(value):
    f = value.read()
    # do logic
    return value


class MyDocument(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(
        upload_to='documents',
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv', ]), validate_doc]
    )
```

or

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(
        label='comment',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'comment'})
    )
    document = forms.FileField(validators=[validate_doc])

    class Meta:
        model = MyDocument
        fields = {'description', 'document'}
```

or remove document field from the form and do validate it via clean_field name method

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
    def clean_document(self):
        doc = self.cleaned_data['document']
        f = doc.read()
        # do logic
        return doc
```

Comment: Thanks, I should use validator for this pattern. but in `validate_doc even` when I try to open `pd.read_csv(value.path)` it returns `FileNotFoundError`, because at this moment real file is not created yet. is it possible to open the file here before created???

Comment: @whitebear value is a file uploaded in memory, you don't need to open it from path. you can simply do value.read().

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I use `io` to read from memory `import io  
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(value.read()))` it works perfectly!!!

Comment: You welcome, @whitebear! I've edited my answer to include also how to manage the uploaded file.